# Measuring performance using cross-validation on the full dataset after training on a subset of that dataset?

Tags: python, cross-validation, supervised-learning, hyperparameter

In my Python code below, I'm measuring the performance of my model using cross-validation. I'm doing it with my full dataset (X,y). This is after I trained on a subset of that data (X_train, y_train). Is this ok? Or because X,y includes my data that I trained on, should I not use it to measure the performance?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X , y, test_size=0.3, random_state=7)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ('reg', LinearRegression())
])

pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)


cross_val_score(pipeline, X, y, cv=k).mean()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to **only** evaluate using cross-validation, you need to do it like this:

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ('reg', LinearRegression())
])

k = ...  # define k

cross_val_score(pipeline, X, y, cv=k).mean()
```

Notes:

1. `cross_val_score` also fits your models so you don't need to fit it beforehand. It will split your dataset into train/test sets `k` times and for each will fit the model and evaluate it.
2. You do this on the whole dataset (i.e. `X` and `y`), so no need for a `train_test_split`.

As a final comment, cross-validation is often used in combination with a holdout-test set to perform hyperparameter tuning using CV and evaluate, finally, on the test set.

Comment: If possible use resampling to penalize for all arbitrary choices, without additional holdout samples.   More comprehensive resampling, i.e., repeating more of the analysis decisions, will all  you to study volatility of such decision making while getting more precise estimates of model performance.